# CSS and if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

```
if(smaxResult<sigma){
    document.getElementById('smaxResult').innerHTML = "Max strain is: " + smaxResult + "<σ(επ)  text1";
} else{
    document.getElementById('smaxResult').innerHTML = "Max strain is: " + smaxResult + ">σ(επ)  text2";
}
```

Hello! i have this condition, and I want when the `(smaxResult < sigma)` occurs the `<σ(επ) text1` to turn out green or else the `>σ(επ) text2` to turn out red  (I mean the color of the font).

Any advise?
thank you.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? What's going wrong in your code? How, and when, are you retrieving the `smaxResult`, what's `sigma`? Do you have any HTML that might be relevant to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two classes `red` and `green` and wrap the text you want to colorize by `span` then add class to this span according to the condition :

```
var elem = document.getElementById('smaxResult');

if(smaxResult<sigma){
    elem.innerHTML = "Max strain is: " + smaxResult + "<σ(επ)  text1";
    elem.classList.add("green");
} else{
    elem.innerHTML = "Max strain is: " + smaxResult + ">σ(επ)  text2";
    elem.classList.add("red");
}
```

CSS :

```
.red{
    color: red;
}

.green{
    color: green;
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('smaxResult');

var elem = document.getElementById('smaxResult');
var smaxResult = 5;
var sigma = 20;

if(smaxResult<sigma){
  elem.innerHTML = "Max strain is: " + smaxResult + " <span><σ(επ)  text1</span>";
  elem.querySelector('span').classList.add("green");
} else{
  elem.innerHTML = "Max strain is: " + smaxResult + " <span>>σ(επ)  text2</span>";
  elem.querySelector('span').classList.add("red");
}
```

```css
.red{
    color: red;
}

.green{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<span id="smaxResult">Some text for test</span>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! it helped but i wanted as you can see in this photo: http://i.imgur.com/oJQ3bCz.png  to be green only the text in the red cycle. But that's ok, Thank you very much.

Comment: What if one of the classes has already been applied and the function runs again in other circumstances? You should check for that.

Comment: Thanks for your intervention @NikxDa .. if so we could remove all the classe first using `elem.querySelector('span').className = "";` or just remove the specific one using `elem.querySelector('span').classList.remove(className)`.

Comment: Removing all the classes will not work because the element might have other classes. Check if the classList contains one of the elements, if so, remove it. I'd wrap this behaviour in a sub-function.

Comment: @ZahosGk - really, seriously, do **not** name your classes "red" and "green".  Name your classes for what things _are_ or what they _represent_, **not** for how they look.  If `(result < sigma)` represents being within tolerance and therefore a good result, for example, you could tag that span as `<span class="goodresult">` and otherwise have `<span class="badresult">` -- this gives it _meaning_ (semantic) -- the decision to make "good" be green and "bad" be red is a stylistic decision that should be confined to the CSS, not part of the class name in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this comment:
[CSS and if condition in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40313998/css-and-if-condition-in-javascript/40314027?noredirect=1#comment67886344_40314027)

With the accepted answer, you will also need to check whether one of the classes is already set on the element, and if it is, remove it. For this, use the following function:

```
function applyClass (el, name, classes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) 
        if (el.classList.contains (classes [i])) 
            el.classList.remove (classes [i]);

    el.classList.add (name);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
applyClass (document.querySelector ("span"), "red", ["red", "green"]);
```

This function can be used for any amount of possible classes and helps to prevent unwanted behaviour if some classes are applied multiple times.